# Why does my Angular project pipeline keep failing?

Tags: node.js, angular, git, npm, gitlab

I have a angular project that I'm trying to tag and push to dev server using git and gitlab.

After my 4th unsuccessful try, I'm now at a loss to what I'm doing wrong.

This is my job log:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 12.9.0 (4c96e5ad)
[0;m[0K  on dev-runner yMELGGtz
[0;msection_start:1608540813:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "shell" executor[0;m
[0;m[0KUsing Shell executor...
[0;msection_end:1608540813:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1608540813:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m
[0;mRunning on WIN-AVAH5M2LJ5E...
section_end:1608540814:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1608540814:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m
[0;m[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 50...[0;m
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:/runner/builds/yMELGGtz/0/gitlab_username/project_name-auth-front/.git/
From https://gitlab.com/gitlab_username/project_name-auth-front
 * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/232677922 -> refs/pipelines/232677922
 * [new tag]         v20201221.3              -> v20201221.3
[32;1mChecking out 2e8cffbc as v20201221.3...[0;m
Removing node_modules/
git-lfs/2.10.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.7; git a526ba6b)

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1608540861:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1608540861:restore_cache
[0K[0K[36;1mRestoring cache[0;m
[0;msection_end:1608540862:restore_cache
[0Ksection_start:1608540862:download_artifacts
[0K[0K[36;1mDownloading artifacts[0;m
[0;msection_end:1608540863:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_start:1608540863:build_script
[0K[0K[36;1mRunning before_script and script[0;m
[0;m[32;1m$ npm i[0;m
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue

> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\runner\builds\yMELGGtz\0\gitlab_username\project_name-auth-front\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> @angular/cli@11.0.4 postinstall C:\runner\builds\yMELGGtz\0\gitlab_username\project_name-auth-front\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1650 packages from 1206 contributors and audited 1654 packages in 113.077s

79 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 3 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
[32;1m$ npm run build-dev[0;m

> project_name-auth@0.0.0 build-dev C:\runner\builds\yMELGGtz\0\gitlab_username\project_name-auth-front
> ng build --hmr --base-href /auth/ --deploy-url /auth/

Unknown option: '--hmr'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project_name-auth@0.0.0 build-dev: `ng build --hmr --base-href /auth/ --deploy-url /auth/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project_name-auth@0.0.0 build-dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-21T08_56_23_982Z-debug.log
section_end:1608540984:build_script
[0Ksection_start:1608540984:upload_artifacts_on_failure
[0K[0K[36;1mUploading artifacts for failed job[0;m
[0;msection_end:1608540985:upload_artifacts_on_failure
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
[0;m
```

Please note that my OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and I have replaced gitlab username and project name in the log with *`gitlab_username`* and *`project_name`*. (because it's not my project or my repository)

Comment: Why are you using —hmr for a production build?

Comment: @MikeOne so I'm guessing hmr is the culprit? thank you. can you please tell me how i can disable it for production build?

Comment: You probably have a run script in your package.json called build-dev.. the -hmr flag seems to be in there. However, build-dev is probably the wrong script to run in your pipeline anway. You probably want a production build there.. so something like ng build —prod..

Comment: @MikeOne nevermind. I just found it in my scripts in package.json. thank you so much. EDIT: I saw your second comment after I typed the first part of my comment. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding what @MikeOne wrote in the comment and as stated in webpack [Hot Module Replacement documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/),

> HMR is not intended for use in production, meaning it should only be
> used in development.

Previously, in my `package.json` I had:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --prod --hmr --base-href /auth/ --deploy-url /auth/",
    "build-dev": "ng build --hmr --base-href /auth/ --deploy-url /auth/"
  },
```

So, I just changed it to:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build --prod --base-href /auth/ --deploy-url /auth/",
    "build-dev": "ng build --base-href /auth/ --deploy-url /auth/"
  },
```

And it worked!